# How to set range for ui-slider in emberjs using ui slider

Tags: ember.js, uislider

The template has two sliders [Ui slider ember](https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-slider)

```
{{range-slider min=entryFeeMin max=entryFeeMax step=1 tooltip='always' changed='changed'}}
{{range-slider min=prizePoolMin max=prizePoolMax step=1 tooltip='always' changed='changed'}}
```

I want to set the slider by default to min and max values selected.

eg: if min:10 and max:200 i want the slider to be range to be set default to min and max values.

please help me

Comment: I was also unable to set the range in hbs file. This plugin is based on "noUiSlider", so follow this link https://refreshless.com/nouislider/ and add your range slider in controller file. should work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Finally!! I found the answer. To set the values by default use property value="min,max" for a range slider.

```
eg: {{range-slider min=10 max=100 step=1 tooltip='always' changed='changed'}}
```

to set the slider by default to min and max values selected the answer is below.

```
{{range-slider min=10 max=100 value="10,100" step=1 tooltip='always' changed='changed'}}
```